# Calling initialize when loading an object serialized with YAML

Tags: ruby, yaml

Is it possible to force Ruby to call an initialize method when using YAML.load_file?  I want to call the method in order to provide values for instance variables I do not serialize.  I know I can factor the code into a separate method and call that method after calling YAML.load_file, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to handle this issue.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do?  My first inclination is to create a class that wraps the call to load_file and then provides the values that don't exist in the configuration file.  I'd like to be able to provide a more complete solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can. Since the code you will add is really specific to the class being deserialized, you should consider adding the feature in the class. For instance, let `Foo` be the class you want to deserialize, you can add a class method such as:

```
class Foo
  def self.from_yaml( yaml )
    foo = YAML::load( yaml )
    # edit the foo object here
    foo
  end
end

myFoo = Foo.from_yaml( "myFoo.yaml" )
```