# Ruby YAML parser by passing constructor

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am working on an application that takes input from a YAML file, parses them into objects, and let's them do their thing. The only problem I'm having now, is that the YAML parser seems to ignore the objects "initialize" method. I was counting on the constructor to fill in any instance variables the YAML file was lacking with defaults, as well as store some things in class variables. Here is an example:

```
class Test

    @@counter = 0

    def initialize(a,b)
        @a = a
        @b = b

        @a = 29 if @b == 3

        @@counter += 1
    end

    def self.how_many
        p @@counter
    end

    attr_accessor :a,:b

end

require 'YAML'

a = Test.new(2,3)
s = a.to_yaml
puts s
b = YAML::load(s)
puts b.a
puts b.b
Test.how_many

puts ""

c = Test.new(4,4)
c.b = 3
t = c.to_yaml
puts t
d = YAML::load(t)
puts d.a
puts d.b
Test.how_many
```

I would have expected the above to output:

```
--- !ruby/object:Test
a: 29
b: 3
29
3
2

--- !ruby/object:Test
a: 4
b: 3
29
3
4
```

Instead I got:

```
--- !ruby/object:Test
a: 29
b: 3
29
3
1

--- !ruby/object:Test
a: 4
b: 3
4
3
2
```

I don't understand how it makes these objects without using their defined initialize method. I'm also wondering if there is anyway to force the parser to use the initialize method.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823386/calling-initialize-when-loading-an-object-serialized-with-yaml

Comment: That post is helpful, however it doesn't completely solve my problem. The YAML stream I am parsing from is more complex than a single object, it is many objects, some of which are composed of others.

Comment: Sorry, just trying.  Maybe this is more helpful: To find out _why_ `YAML::load` does _not_ call `initialize`, check the source. :P  Or perhaps we can wait for an answerer that knows more of the details.  I did try `puts d.class == c.class` in your script and found it to be true.  So +1 on your question.

Comment: This should not be a problem but just in any case rename your local vars in constructor to something else since it maybe calling accessors instead of local vars.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deserializing an object from Yaml doesn’t use the `initialize` method because in general there is no correspondance between the object’s instance variables (which is what the default Yaml serialization stores) and the parameters to `initialize`.

As an example, consider an object with an `initialize` that looks like this (with no other instance variables):

```ruby
def initialize(param_one, param_two)
  @a_variable = some_calculation(param_one, param_two)
end
```

Now when an instance of this is deserialized, the Yaml processor has a value for `@a_variable`, but the `initialize` method requires *two* parameters, so it can’t call it. Even if the number of instance variables matches the number of parameters to `initialize` it is not necessarily the case that they correspond, and even if they did the processor doesn’t know the order they shoud be passed to `initialize`.

The default process for serializing and deserializing a Ruby object to Yaml is to write out all instance variables (with their names) during serialization, then when deserializing allocate a new instance of the class and simply set the same instance variables on this new instance.

Of course sometimes you need more control of this process. If you are using the Psych Yaml processor (which is the default in Ruby 1.9.3) then you should implement the `encode_with` (for serialisation) or or `init_with` (for deserialization) methods as appropriate.

For serialization, Psych will call the `encode_with` method of an object if it is present, passing a [`coder` object](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v1.3.4/lib/psych/coder.rb). This object allows you to specify how the object should be represented in Yaml – normally you just treat it like a hash.

For deserialization, Psych will call the `init_with` method if it is present on your object instead of using the default procedure described above, again passing a `coder` object. This time the `coder` will contain the information about the objects representation in Yaml.

Note you don’t need to provide both methods, you can just provide either one if you want. If you do provide both, the `coder` object you get passed in `init_with` will essentially be the same as the one passed to `encode_with` after that method has run.

As an example, consider an object that has some instance variables that are calculated from others (perhaps as an optimisation to avoid a large calculation), but shouldn’t be serialized to the Yaml.

```ruby
class Foo

  def initialize(first, second)
    @first = first
    @second = second
    @calculated = expensive_calculation(@first, @second)
  end

  def encode_with(coder)
    # @calculated shouldn’t be serialized, so we just add the other two.
    # We could provide different names to use in the Yaml here if we
    # wanted (as long as the same names are used in init_with).
    coder['first'] = @first
    coder['second'] = @second
  end

  def init_with(coder)
    # The Yaml only contains values for @first and @second, we need to
    # recalculate @calculated so the object is valid.
    @first = coder['first']
    @second = coder['second']
    @calculated = expensive_calculation(@first, @second)
  end

  # The expensive calculation
  def expensive_calculation(a, b)
    ...
  end
end
```

When you dump an instance of this class to Yaml, it will look something like this, without the `calculated` value:

```yaml
--- !ruby/object:Foo
first: 1
second: 2
```

When you load this Yaml back into Ruby, the created object will have the `@calculated` instance variable set.

If you wanted you *could* call `initialize` from within `init_with`, but I think it would be better to keep the a clear separation between initializing a *new* instance of the class, and deserializing an *existing* instance from Yaml. I would recommend extracting the common logic into methods that can be called from both instead,

Comment: I like the explanation about why it doesn't use the initialize method, which makes sense to me. The question then becomes how to change the behavior of how an object is created when it is loaded from YAML. Above your answer I have two that suggest the use of Object.to_yaml and Object.allocate. So which is it?? Object.init_with, Object.allocate, or Object.to_yaml? I'm guessing you've found documentation on this, can you send me the link?

Comment: @clementine the answer suggesting to use `from_yaml` links to the api for Rubygems, it’s not part of Yaml itself. In the answer from the other Stackoverflow question, `from_yaml` is just used as a plain method, it won’t integrate with the rest of the yaml loading/dumping. `allocate` is fairly low level stuff, I would recommend avoiding interfering with it.

Comment: @clementine The documentation for Psych is pretty poor, but I can offer a link to the source where `init_with` is checked for and the default behaviour occurs if it isn’t there: https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v1.3.4/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb#L291-300.

Comment: +1 This seems like the right way to do it. I'm appalled at how poorly documented this is :)

Answer (score 3):

If you only want this behavior with pure ruby classes that use `@`-style instance variables (not those from compiled extensions and not `Struct`-style), the following should work. YAML seems to call the `allocate` class method when loading an instance of that class, even if the instance is nested as a member of another object. So we can redefine `allocate`. Example:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :yaml_flag
  def self.allocate
    super.tap {|o| o.instance_variables.include?(:@yaml_flag) or o.yaml_flag = true }
  end
end
class Bar
  attr_accessor :foo, :yaml_flag
  def self.allocate
    super.tap {|o| o.instance_variables.include?(:@yaml_flag) or o.yaml_flag = true }
  end
end

>> bar = Bar.new
=> #<Bar:0x007fa40ccda9f8>
>> bar.foo = Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x007fa40ccdf9f8>
>> [bar.yaml_flag, bar.foo.yaml_flag]
=> [nil, nil]
>> bar_reloaded = YAML.load YAML.dump bar
=> #<Bar:0x007fa40cc7dd48 @foo=#<Foo:0x007fa40cc7db90 @yaml_flag=true>, @yaml_flag=true>
>> [bar_reloaded.yaml_flag, bar_reloaded.foo.yaml_flag]
=> [true, true]

# won't overwrite false
>> bar.foo.yaml_flag = false
=> false
>> bar_reloaded = YAML.load YAML.dump bar
=> #<Bar:0x007fa40ccf3098 @foo=#<Foo:0x007fa40ccf2f08 @yaml_flag=false>, @yaml_flag=true>
>> [bar_reloaded.yaml_flag, bar_reloaded.foo.yaml_flag]
=> [true, false]

# won't overwrite nil
>> bar.foo.yaml_flag = nil
=> nil
>> bar_reloaded = YAML.load YAML.dump bar
=> #<Bar:0x007fa40cd73518 @foo=#<Foo:0x007fa40cd73360 @yaml_flag=nil>, @yaml_flag=true>
>> [bar_reloaded.yaml_flag, bar_reloaded.foo.yaml_flag]
=> [true, nil]
```

I intentionally avoided a `o.nil?` check in the `tap` blocks because `nil` may actually be a meaningful value that you don't want to overwrite.

One last caveat: `allocate` may be used by third party libraries (or by your own code), and you may not want to set the members in those cases. If you want to restrict allocation, to just yaml loading, you'll have to do something more fragile and complex like check the `caller` stack in the allocate method to see if yaml is calling it.

I'm on ruby 1.9.3 (with psych) and the top of the stack looks like this (path prefix removed):

```
psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:274:in `revive'",
psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:219:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'",
psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'",
psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'",
psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'",
psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:231:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'",
psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'",
psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'",
psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'",
psych/nodes/node.rb:35:in `to_ruby'",
psych.rb:128:in `load'",
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Object.tap, but thanks, this looks exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @clementine `tap` is really convenient. See [the ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap). It lets you do things to an object without having to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

> [from_yaml(input)](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Specification.html#method-c-from_yaml)
>
> Special loader for YAML files. **When a [Specification](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Specification.html) object is loaded from a YAML file, it bypasses the normal Ruby object initialization routine (initialize).** This method makes up for that and deals with gems of different ages.
>
> input can be anything that YAML.load() accepts: String or IO.

This is the reason that the initialize method was not being run when you executed `YAML::Load`.

Comment: Good find. Does that mean I can solve this by overriding the from_yaml class method?, like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823386/calling-initialize-when-loading-an-object-serialized-with-yaml  <-- the problem I had with this is that it was loading a single object from a YAML stream. The yaml file I'll be loading is a complex heirarchy of objects, all of which need to go through the default constructor

Comment: You could use [YAML::load_documents](http://yaml4r.sourceforge.net/doc/page/loading_yaml_documents.htm) to accomplish this.

Comment: No you miss understand... it isn't multiple yaml streams in the same file. It is one yaml stream describing a hierarchy of objects in composition. So for example, I may have an object tree that contains fruit, leaves, maybe a birds nest, all of which need to be unserialized into a ruby object