# YAML initialise with default value on deserialisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am still using `Syck` as my `YAML::ENGINE` due to other reasons.
I am deserializing an YAML file with Custom object.

```
OBJECTS:
  :user: !ruby/object:User  
    name: Jack
    role: Developer
```

I have a `User` class. It is not `ActiveRecord Model`. 
I have other instance variable in my class which is not assigned in YAML file. But I want to assign a default value for it when YAML file is deserialised.

I have seen this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821534/ruby-yaml-parser-by-passing-constructor). `init_with` and `encode_with` works with Psyck engine.
How can I achieve this with `Syck` as YAML Engine.?